# Cannot find "$(SRCROOT) agvtool | increment_build_number | Fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, fastlane

The avgtool associated with increment_build_number plugin in Fastlane returning error.

When I'm running `increment_build_number` in Fastlane, I'm getting

> ```
> Updating CFBundleVersion in Info.plist(s)...
>
> $(SRCROOT)/Info.plist
> Cannot find "$(SRCROOT)/Info.plist"
> ```

The reason for the issue is that the avgtool couldn't identify the $(SRCROOT)

One of the solution found is to update the path to the Info.plist in Xcode settings to absolute path.

As there are a number of developers working on this project, updating the project settings with absolute path (to the plist) will affect others to build the project.

Is there any other way I can get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The current solution to your problem would be to remove the $(SRCROOT) from your build settings. $(SRCROOT) means "directory where .xcodeproj is" so you will be perfectly fine to remove it (Xcode will still look for it relatively from the .xcodeproj).

We've recently removed agvtool from the `get_version_number` action (in version `2.87.0` in favor of using the `xcodeproj` gem where we can more nicely handle which target is found, handle $(SRCROOT), and remove that "avgtool setup process". I will be working on replacing agvtool in `increment_build_number` and `get_build_number` soon which should hopefully prevent further issues like this one.

Answer (score 15):

You can open the project setting and find the key **INFOPLIST_FILE**

- `INFOPLIST_FILE = "$(SRCROOT)/ProjectName-info.plist";`

Then remove the `$(SRCROOT)` and **make sure** that after you **change Xcode** still finding your info plist

The new value may be:

- `INFOPLIST_FILE = "/ProjectName-info.plist";`
- `INFOPLIST_FILE = "/MyProjectFolderName/ProjectName-info.plist";`

Comment: I had to skip the first / to get it to work properly.

Comment: Yes, belong to your project settings. I thought so. Just make sure Xcode can read the Plist file.