# Increment Bundle Version Error - Fastfile

Tags: macos, github-actions, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I have the following Fastfile that I'm using to upload a TestFlight build of a MacOS app:

```
# Fastfile
default_platform(:mac)

DEVELOPER_APP_ID = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_ID"]
APP_IDENTIFIER = ENV["APP_IDENTIFIER"]
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = ""
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
APPLE_ISSUER_ID = ENV["APPLE_ISSUER_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_ID = ENV["APPLE_KEY_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_CONTENT = ENV["APPLE_KEY_CONTENT"]
GIT_AUTHORIZATION = ENV["GIT_AUTHORIZATION"]
TEAM_ID = '752MACT599'
ORG_NAME = 'Meter'
PROJECT_NAME = 'Meter'
SIGH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME = "com.meter.vpn-client1 AppStore"

def delete_temp_keychain(name)
  delete_keychain(
    name: name
  ) if File.exist? File.expand_path("~/Library/Keychains/#{name}-db")
end

def create_temp_keychain(name, password)
  create_keychain(
    name: name,
    password: password,
    unlock: false,
    timeout: 0
  )
end

def ensure_temp_keychain(name, password)
  delete_temp_keychain(name)
  create_temp_keychain(name, password)
end

update_fastlane

desc 'Build, Archive, and Upload to App Store Connect'
lane :release do |options|
  is_nightly = 0

  app_identifier = ENV['APP_IDENTIFIER']
  scheme = 'Meter'
  configuration = 'Release'

  UI.message("Debug: Creating App Store Connect API key...")

  keychain_name = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER
  keychain_password = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD
  ensure_temp_keychain(keychain_name, keychain_password)

  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: APPLE_KEY_ID,
    issuer_id: APPLE_ISSUER_ID,
    key_content: APPLE_KEY_CONTENT,
    duration: 1200,
    in_house: false
  )

  increment_build_number(
    xcodeproj: "Meter.xcodeproj"
  )
  
  match(
    # app_identifier: app_identifier,
    git_basic_authorization: Base64.strict_encode64(GIT_AUTHORIZATION),
    additional_cert_types: 'mac_installer_distribution',
    readonly: false,
    keychain_name: keychain_name,
    keychain_password: keychain_password,
    api_key: api_key,
    platform: "macos"
  )
  cert(
    keychain_path: "~/Library/Keychains/#{keychain_name}-db",
    keychain_password: keychain_password,
    api_key: api_key,
    platform: "macos"
  )
  sigh(
    app_identifier: app_identifier,
    readonly: false,
    cert_id: lane_context[SharedValues::CERT_CERTIFICATE_ID],
    provisioning_name: ENV['SIGH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME'],
    ignore_profiles_with_different_name: true,
    api_key: api_key,
    platform: "macos"
  )

  update_project_team(
    path: "Meter.xcodeproj",
    teamid: TEAM_ID
  )

  gym(
    project: 'Meter.xcodeproj',
    scheme: scheme,
    export_method: 'app-store',
    configuration: configuration,
    clean: false,
    derived_data_path: './build',
    xcargs: "WARNING_CFLAGS='$(inherited)'",
    skip_profile_detection: true,
  )

  upload_to_testflight(
    app_identifier: app_identifier,
    skip_submission: true,
    skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
    pkg: './Meter.pkg'
  )
end
```

I keep getting the following error; even though I am incrementing the bundle id:

```
[19:42:32]: Successfully exported and signed the pkg file:
[19:42:32]: /Users/runner/work/client-app-swift/client-app-swift/Meter.pkg
[19:42:32]: ----------------------------------
[19:42:32]: --- Step: upload_to_testflight ---
[19:42:32]: ----------------------------------
[19:42:32]: Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API
[19:42:33]: Ready to upload new build to TestFlight (App: 6449044498)...
[19:42:33]: Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[19:42:33]: This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
[19:42:39]: [altool] 2023-09-27 19:42:39.760 *** Error: The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version: '27'. (ID: a4eed95a-923c-40d7-a697-0c47012fe8be) (-19232)

[19:42:39]: [altool]  {

[19:42:39]: [altool]     NSLocalizedDescription = "The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used";

[19:42:39]: [altool]     NSLocalizedFailureReason = "The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version: \U201827\U2019. (ID: a4eed95a-923c-40d7-a697-0c47012fe8be)";

[19:42:39]: [altool]     NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=IrisAPI Code=-19241 \"The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used\" UserInfo={status=409, detail=The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version., source={\n    pointer = \"/data/attributes/cfBundleVersion\";\n}, id=a4eed95a-923c-40d7-a697-0c47012fe8be, code=ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE, title=The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used, meta={\n    previousBundleVersion = 27;\n}, NSLocalizedDescription=The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version.}";

[19:42:39]: [altool]     "iris-code" = "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE";

[19:42:39]: [altool]     previousBundleVersion = 27;

[19:42:39]: [altool] }

[19:42:39]: Application Loader output above ^
[19:42:39]: Error uploading '/var/folders/r_/vbvvglrx3lvds6dp_mbyq3_c0000gn/T/881530bf-4d94-4419-84f8-32cb1b667364.pkg'.

[19:42:39]: The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version: '27'. (ID: a4eed95a-923c-40d7-a697-0c47012fe8be) (-19232)

[19:42:39]: The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
[19:42:39]: Could not download/upload from App Store Connect!
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                              Lane Context                                                                                               |
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM                   | mac                                                                                                                                                                |
| PLATFORM_NAME                      |                                                                                                                                                                    |
| LANE_NAME                          | release                                                                                                                                                            |
| KEYCHAIN_PATH                      | ~/Library/Keychains/***                                                                                                                                        |
| BUILD_NUMBER                       | 2                                                                                                                                                                  |
| SIGH_PROFILE_TYPE                  | app-store                                                                                                                                                          |
| MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING | {"***"=>"match AppStore *** macos", "***.extension"=>"match AppStore ***.extension macos"} |
| CERT_FILE_PATH                     | /Users/runner/work/client-app-swift/client-app-swift/7532RULTT7.cer                                                                                                |
| CERT_CERTIFICATE_ID                | 7532RULTT7                                                                                                                                                         |
| SIGH_PROFILE_PATH                  | /Users/runner/work/client-app-swift/client-app-swift/AppStore_***.provisionprofile                                                               |
| SIGH_PROFILE_PATHS                 | ["/Users/runner/work/client-app-swift/client-app-swift/AppStore_***.provisionprofile"]                                                           |
| SIGH_UDID                          | 61cc4105-d494-4957-a18a-1a757e194d34                                                                                                                               |
| SIGH_UUID                          | 61cc4105-d494-4957-a18a-1a757e194d34                                                                                                                               |
| SIGH_NAME                          | match AppStore *** macos                                                                                                                         |
| PKG_OUTPUT_PATH                    | /Users/runner/work/client-app-swift/client-app-swift/Meter.pkg                                                                                                     |
| XCODEBUILD_ARCHIVE                 | /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-09-27/Meter 2023-09-27 19.39.33.xcarchive                                                                      |
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[19:42:39]: Error uploading pkg file: 
 [Application Loader Error Output]: Error uploading '/var/folders/r_/vbvvglrx3lvds6dp_mbyq3_c0000gn/T/881530bf-4d94-4419-84f8-32cb1b667364.pkg'.
[Application Loader Error Output]: The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version: '27'. (ID: a4eed95a-923c-40d7-a697-0c47012fe8be) (-19232)
[Application Loader Error Output]: The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.

+------------------------------------------------+
|                fastlane summary                |

[!] Error uploading pkg file: 
 [Application Loader Error Output]: Error uploading '/var/folders/r_/vbvvglrx3lvds6dp_mbyq3_c0000gn/T/881530bf-4d94-4419-84f8-32cb1b667364.pkg'.
[Application Loader Error Output]: The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version: '27'. (ID: a4eed95a-923c-40d7-a697-0c47012fe8be) (-19232)
[Application Loader Error Output]: The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                    | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform          | 0           |
| 2    | update_fastlane           | 5           |
| 3    | create_keychain           | 0           |
| 4    | app_store_connect_api_key | 0           |
| 5    | increment_build_number    | 6           |
| 6    | match                     | 4           |
| 7    | cert                      | 0           |
| 8    | sigh                      | 0           |
| 9    | update_project_team       | 0           |
| 10   | gym                       | 299         |
|    | upload_to_testflight      | 6           |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+

[19:42:39]: fastlane finished with errors
```

Answer (score 1):

I see:

```
[19:42:39]: [altool] 2023-09-27 19:42:39.760 *** 
Error: The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used
The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version: '27'. 
(ID: a4eed95a-923c-40d7-a697-0c47012fe8be) (-19232)
```

Meaning, the new build you are trying to upload to [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) has a [bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/bundles-and-frameworks) version number that already exists in the App Store Connect.
This typically happens if the new build version you are attempting to upload is the same as or lower than the version of the build that has been previously uploaded.

Your [Fastfile](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/Fastfile/) includes the `increment_build_number` action:

```rb
increment_build_number(
  xcodeproj: "Meter.xcodeproj"
)
```

This action should increment the build number in your Xcode project, but the error suggests it is not the case.

So make sure you are incrementing the correct attribute; iOS and macOS applications have both a `CFBundleVersion` (Build Number) and a `CFBundleShortVersionString` (Version Number), as mentioned [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error#comment44983811_6037025). If you are only incrementing one but not the other, you may still run into this error.

You can add `--verbose` to your `fastlane` command to get more details, which could give you a clue about why the build number is not being incremented as expected.

```bash
fastlane release --verbose
```

And you can also add debug statements before and after the `increment_build_number` action to print the current build number. This can help you understand whether it is getting incremented or not.

```rb
before_build_number = get_build_number(
  xcodeproj: "Meter.xcodeproj"
)
UI.message("Build number before increment: #{before_build_number}")

increment_build_number(
  xcodeproj: "Meter.xcodeproj"
)

after_build_number = get_build_number(
  xcodeproj: "Meter.xcodeproj"
)
UI.message("Build number after increment: #{after_build_number}")
```

Comment: So, I tried this:

  latest_build = latest_testflight_build_number(
    app_identifier: ENV['APP_IDENTIFIER']
  )


 increment_build_number(
    build_number: incremented_build
  )

but still getting the error

Comment: @narner You may need to debug each step to ensure the `latest_build` is what you expect and that `increment_build_number` effectively updates the build number in your project before attempting to upload again.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem. `increment_build_number` didn't actually work for me, and I think it's because I'm using nativescript. See below for more details. My solution required me to use regex to manually update the `Info.plist` file.

### Solution

1. I created a custom lane to get and set a new build number. I needed to do this so I could pass the new build number to a shell script,

   ```rb
   desc 'Auto increments and sets the build number.'
   lane :setBuildNumber do |options|
       app_identifier = options[:app_identifier]
       live = options[:live] || false
       api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
           key_id: ENV['APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_KEY_ID'],
           issuer_id: ENV['APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_ISSUER_ID'],
           key_content: ENV['APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_KEY']
       )
       build_number = app_store_build_number(
           api_key: api_key, 
           live: live,
           app_identifier: app_identifier
       )
       build_number = build_number + 1
       sh("cd ../ && EXPLICIT_BUILD_NUMBER=#{build_number} make set-versions-explicit")
       UI.message "Set Build Number to #{build_number} for #{app_identifier}."
   end
   ```
2. The shell script simply calls a regex on the file that needs changing,

   ```bash
   perl -0777 -i -pe 's/CFBundleVersion.*\n.*<\/string>/CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n    <string>$(EXPLICIT_BUILD_NUMBER)<\/string>/g' App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist
   ```
3. I call the `setBuildNumber` lane **before** I run `ns prepare ios` to ensure that the generated `$(SRCROOT)/nativesriptapp/nativesriptapp-Info.plist` file has the correct build number,

   ```rb
   setBuildNumber(app_identifier: package_name)
   sh("ns", "prepare", "ios", "--release", "--clean", "--env.production", "--env.env=prod")
   ```

### Discussion

Getting fastlane to build ios in ci/cd wasn't as trivial as android. Before I encountered this problem, I fist had to get the [archive to build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77228659/7562578).

When I first encountered the error, `The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used`, I tried setting the `build_number` in multiple places including before I ran `build_app`, `upload_to_testflight`, and the lane context variable `LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER`. None of those actually changed the build number in the built ipa file. Ultimately what solved the problem for me was manually updating the correct  `Info.plist` file.

This didn't work for me,

```
api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(...etc...)
build_num = app_store_build_number(...etc...)
increment_build_number(
    build_number: build_num,
    xcodeproj: "./platforms/ios/APP.xcodeproj" # canonical nativescript path
)
```

as it failed with error,

```
[11:20:26]: ▸ Setting version of project nativesriptapp to:
[11:20:26]: ▸ 19.
[11:20:26]: ▸ Also setting CFBundleVersion key (assuming it exists)
[11:20:26]: ▸ Updating CFBundleVersion in Info.plist(s)...
[11:20:26]: ▸ $(SRCROOT)/nativesriptapp/nativesriptapp-Info.plist
[11:20:26]: ▸ Cannot find "$(SRCROOT)/nativesriptapp/nativesriptapp-Info.plist"
[11:20:26]: ▸ /Users/../code/
[11:20:26]: Cannot set build number with plist path containing $(SRCROOT)
[11:20:26]: Please remove $(SRCROOT) in your Xcode target build settings
```

It turns out `agvtool` was failing and people have [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429944/cannot-find-srcroot-agvtool-increment-build-number-fastlane) questions about it and the recommended [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49466742/7562578) is to remove `$(SRCROOT)` from the path. This wasn't an option for me as these files are generated by nativescript. Instead, we had to use a perl command in a makefile to update the CFBundleVersion in our `Info.plist`,

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/CFBundleVersion.*\n.*<\/string>/CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n    <string>$(BUILD_NUMBER)<\/string>/g' App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist
```

so in fastlane we call this command,

```
sh("cd ../ && BUILD_NUMBER=#{build_number} make set-versions")
```

You could call a similar regex in any other way using `sh`. That side stepped having to use the `increment_build_number`. Note that for us, we had to update the correct `Info.plist` file before we ran our nativescript prepare commands, that way the `Info.plist` in the xcode project directory used the new build number. You'll see in the output above our source `Info.plist` and the generated one after running `ns prepare ios`,

```
App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist # We customize this file
$(SRCROOT)/nativesriptapp/nativesriptapp-Info.plist # ns prepare ios creates this file with the one above.
```

The other gotchas was nativescript can also use the .env file to set the build numberin the generated Info.plist, so we needed to change one more file,

```bash
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/BUILD_NUMBER=.*/BUILD_NUMBER=$(EXPLICIT_BUILD_NUMBER)/g' env/.env.base
```

Passing the `--verbose` flag and running some of these lanes locally ultimately helped me solve this. It's a slow process because I can't run gitactions locally on MacOS even with using act.